# DataTable to Pre Defined DataGridView Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DGV with pre defined columns as below and here are generation method and binding method

```
fixGridAlarm(dgvAlarmlar);


public void fixGridAlarm(DataGridView gvw)
    {
        gvw.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gvw.RowTemplate.Height = 75;
        gvw.ColumnCount = 3;
        gvw.Columns[0].Name = "No";
        gvw.Columns[0].Width = 60;
        gvw.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
        gvw.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        gvw.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        gvw.Columns[1].Name = "Tarih/Saat";
        gvw.Columns[1].Width = 490;
        gvw.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
        gvw.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        gvw.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        gvw.Columns[2].Name = "Açıklama";
        gvw.Columns[2].Width = 1195;
        gvw.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
        gvw.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        gvw.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

        BindAlarmlarGrid();

    }


    public void BindAlarmlarGrid()
    {
        string CSVFilePathName = pathAlarms;
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        string[] Fields;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(dgvAlarmlar.Columns[0].Name, typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add(dgvAlarmlar.Columns[1].Name, typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add(dgvAlarmlar.Columns[2].Name, typeof(string));
        DataRow Row;
        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            Row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++)
            {
                Row[f] = Fields[f];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(Row);
        }
        dgvAlarmlar.DataSource = dt;
```

When i give its `DataSource` as a `DataTable` columns are added next to the original DGV how can i bind it on the original grid instead of the next?

Comment: dont you have to call `dgvAlarmlar.DataBind();` after `dgvAlarmlar.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: It is winform not asp.net @AlexW

Comment: im finding it hard to see what the problem is

Comment: When i bind it, that adds extra columns and leaves my pre defined columns empty, I dont want extra columns, I want my pre defined columns to be filled. @AlexW

Comment: you are adding the first column 3 times but with different type each time. Could that be it?

Comment: I dont have VS to test it out, but what does `Row` look like before you add it to `dt`

Comment: have you tried `dt.Rows.Add(Fields);`

Comment: you may have to post a screen shot of the grid, so I can see what the result is. I can only do so much without VS

Comment: Thank you @AlexW that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with changing my binding method like that instead of using `DataTable`

```
public void BindAlarmlarGrid()
    {
        string CSVFilePathName = pathAlarms;
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
        string[] Fields;

        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            dgvAlarmlar.Rows.Add(Fields);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Data binding requires you to set the [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx) property, as explained in the **Remarks** section of the MSDN documentation:

> When the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true, each column automatically sets its DataPropertyName property to the name of a property or database column in the data source specified by the DataSource property. This binding can also be performed manually, which is useful when you want to display only a subset of the properties or database columns available in the data source. In such cases, set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false, and then manually add each DataGridViewColumn, setting the value of each DataPropertyName property to the properties or database columns in the data source that you want to display.

You can make your original code work for instance like this:

```
public void fixGridAlarm(DataGridView gvw)
{
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < gvw.Columns.Count; i++)
        gvw.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = gvw.Columns[i].Name;
    BindAlarmlarGrid();
}
```